# Wordpress Admin "New Feature:" popup always displayed

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have one small error in the backend wordpress. It always show me the info panel , is like it doesn't know if I already I have been in this part of the admin or not. After that some behaviors in the backed are not ok.

Could be a problem with cookies ?

[image]

Comment: WordPress version? Have you tried disabling all the plugins and reverting to the default theme? The flag to display those is stored in the `_usermeta` table on a per-user basis, not the cookies. Does this happen for other users?

Comment: yes, I a bit strange. Let me ckeck the db